# How to return 1 piece of json data

Tags: c#, json

I'm struggling a bit with this json, my 1st error was:

```
 $exception {"Error converting value 167 to type 'Web.Domain.Ean.HotelList'. Path '', line 1, position 3."} System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException}
```

So I have been trying different ways of trying to get it to work and now I think I have made a complete mess of my code, and now I get this error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Domain.Ean.HotelCount>'
```

Can anyone with a fresh pair off eyes please take a look and see if they can help with the error and if possible also **explain some json theory** to help me learn.

```
public class HotelCount
{
    public string ActivePropertyCount { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<HotelCount> GetNumberOfHotels()
{
    var numberOfHotelCount = GetHotelsFromEan.GetListOfHotels();
    var root = JObject.Parse(numberOfHotelCount.ToString());
    IList<JToken> hotelCount = root["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"].Children().ToList();

    IList<HotelCount> count = new List<HotelCount>();
    foreach (JToken hotel in hotelCount)
    {
        HotelCount countHotels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.ToString());
        count.Add(countHotels);
    }

    var t = count.FirstOrDefault();
    //IList<HotelCount> numberOfHotels = hotelCount.Select(count => JsonConvert
    //                             .DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(
    //                             count.SingleOrDefault().ToString())).ToList();
    return t.ActivePropertyCount;
}
```

Thanks
George

=========================Updated code===============================

```
public string GetNumberOfHotels()
        {
            var numberOfHotelCount = GetHotelsFromEan.GetListOfHotels();
            var root = JObject.Parse(numberOfHotelCount.ToString());

            IList<JToken> hotelCount = root["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"].Children().ToList();

            IList<HotelCount> count = hotelCount.Select(hotel => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.ToString())).ToList();


            return count.ToString();
        }
```

==============================New update================================

The json value is in the format {"@activePropertyCount":"167","

So my class is:

```
public class HotelCount
    {
        public string ActivePropertyCount { get; set; }
    }
```

My last error was.

Message=Error converting value 167 to type 'Web.Domain.Ean.HotelCount'
Message=Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to Web.Domain.Ean.HotelCount.

So if I go back to the code below, what needs to be done to return the value of ActivePropertyCount

```
public IEnumerable<HotelCount> GetNumberOfHotels()
        {
            var numberOfHotelCount = GetHotelsFromEan.GetListOfHotels();
            var root = JObject.Parse(numberOfHotelCount.ToString());

            IList<JToken> hotelCount = root["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"].Children().ToList();

            IList<HotelCount> count = new List<HotelCount>();
            foreach (JToken hotel in hotelCount)
            {
                HotelCount countHotels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
                count.Add(countHotels);
            }

            return count;

        }
```

======================Fixed it=========================

```
public string GetNumberOfHotels()
        {
            var numberOfHotelCount = GetHotelsFromEan.GetListOfHotels();
            var root = JObject.Parse(numberOfHotelCount.ToString());

            IList<JToken> hotelCount = root["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"].Children().Values().ToList();

            var s = hotelCount.FirstOrDefault();
            var t = s;

           // IList<HotelCount> count = hotelCount.Select(hotel => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.FirstOrDefault().ToString()).ActivePropertyCount).ToList();

            return t.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what you have got but try this (guessing jToken property was **ActivePropertyCount** but substitute as required):

```
public string GetNumberOfHotels()
{      
    var numberOfHotelCount = GetHotelsFromEan.GetListOfHotels();
    var root = JObject.Parse(numberOfHotelCount.ToString());

    // Get list of hotels
    IList<JToken> hotels = root["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"].Children().ToList()
        .Select(hotel => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.ToString())).ToList();

    // Now get ActivePropertyCount for each hotel
    int totalCount = 0;
    foreach (JToken jToken in hotels)
    {
        totalCount += jToken.Value<int>("ActivePropertyCount");
    }
    return totalCount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Belogix ActivePropertyCount is an actually number of hotels, not a count. > json returned @activePropertyCount":"167" so @activePropertyCount" is returned as a string

Comment: Hi Belogix, still get error: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Web.Domain.Ean.HotelCount. This line of code is throwing error:  HotelCount countHotels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelCount>(hotel.ToString());

Comment: This line show correct number foreach (JToken hotel in hotelCount)

Comment: Hi Belogix, sorry still does not work, just need to try and get value from (JToken hotel in hotelCount) as that shows correct value

Comment: @CareerChange - I think I might see what you trying (I hope)!

Comment: Great, well done @CareerChange I hope I helped you a little! These things can be a pain to track down!